# Most efficient data structure for Prim-Jarnik's algorithm

Tags: data-structures, prims-algorithm

What is the most efficient data structure among these there:

- Edge list
- Adjacency list
- Adjacency matrix

for executing Prim-Jarnik's algorithm and why?

Comment: What did you already try to figure out the answer yourself?

Comment: Where do you have this list from? Is there something written about what the con's/pro's of each approach are? If not, did you think about the arguments for/against each approach? What did you find out?

Comment: Don't just post exercise questions without even thinking about the solution. At least show some effort. It is not neccessary that you have come up with an answer (otherwise you wouldn't ask here). But you should show us what you have tried to figure it out. This is not a website to solve your homework for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By edge list I suppose you mean the list of all edges in a graph G ? Then that is the slowest of the three since you would need to traverse the entire list each time you are at a vertice u just to know which (u, v) pairs are in G. Adjacency matrix is somewhat faster than that, but still slow since you will need to traverse an entire row of the matrix to find the adjacent vertices and the respective edge weights. But if you have a dense graph, the adjacency matrix is just like an adjacency list. Adjacency list is the faster one supposing a not so dense graph such that traversing the list isn't more costly than directly accessing each column in the matrix row.

Said that, the key issue in Prim's algorithm is not actually this. To achieve its described computational complexity, you need to use a priority queue (and this is the part you should be concerned).